# rc-update command can not be found in docker gentoo image

Tags: gentoo

My docker image is `tianon/gentoo-stage3:latest`
And my host system is centos7 and my docker version is `Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651`

When I run this image , I found I can not use `rc-update` command. `ls -l /sbin/rc*` show empty result.

I have no idea what package I need to install.

Answer (score 1):

rc-update is provided by the sys-apps/openrc package. Why you don't have it is a mystery without knowing more about the image / setup. The image may be using systemd, but that doesn't necessarily rule out the openrc package being installed.

You should run: `ps -p 1 -o command`. That will give you an indication of your init system. If it says systemd, whatever you are trying to do with `rc-update` should probably be done with the `systemctl` command instead.

If you are indeed using sysvinit / openrc, I suggest you update your openrc package by `emerge -a openrc` That will restore the rc-update command.